# How to change style for radio button childs in IONIC using angularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-radio name="choiceLng" ng-model="language" value="y" ng-value="'y'" ng-change="langChanged('y')">y</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio name="choiceLng" ng-model="language" value="x" ng-value="'x'" ng-change="langChanged('x')">x</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

I created radio buttons using ion-list. I want to change style for childs of 
`ion-radio` which are the `input` tag and the `div`. How can I "reach" this `input` tag and then change css dynamically using angularJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `default` class on all `ion-radio` element. Then with proper CSS selector you can add style for its content like

```
.default .item-content {
 // To add style to content label along with its background
}
.default .radio-icon {
 // To add style to content label tick icon (or to modify it when not shown)
}
```

Then you can make use of `ng-class` and check value of ngModel language with its ng-value to apply particular class say `selected` to that label tag.
In your case it's as follows

```
<ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-radio name="choiceLng" ng-class="{'selected': language === 'y'}" ng-model="language" value="y" ng-value="'y'" ng-change="langChanged('y')">y</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio name="choiceLng" ng-class="{'selected': language === 'x'}" ng-model="language" value="x" ng-value="'x'" ng-change="langChanged('x')">x</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

Now here you're using ion-radio static so need to add that ng-class too every option but if you're using ng-repeat on it, it'll be only once just to compare model with ng-value variable.
After along with model change `selected` class will be added to only selected radio option so you can have CSS for its contents the same way:

```
.selected .item-content {
 // To add style to selected content label along with its background
}
.selected .radio-icon {
 // To add style to selected content label tick icon (or to modify it)
}
```

Working **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shantanu_kulkarrni/pen/QOmvrY)** example to refer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add additional classes you can add this to you `ionic.app.scss` file:

```
label.item.item-radio.ng-valid
  border-radius: 400px
  margin: 5px 50px 5px 10px
```